# Implement recursive calculations for my mortgage calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

javascript experts!

I am developing my mortgage calculator and it looks like I need your help badly.

My app is implementing conventional mortgage calculator where you input mortgage amount, term and interest rate and it is supposed to provide a loan payments breakdown by months using Jquery datatables plugin.

So far my html is:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

    //restrict input to certain types
    $('[restrict]').on('keyup', function () {
        switch ($(this).attr('restrict')) {
        case 'integer':
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ''));
        case 'float':
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\.0-9]*/g, ''));
        }
    });

    $('#breakdown').on('click', () => {
        //get the array of payments
        var amount = $('#amount').val();
        var months = $('#term').val();
        var interest = $('#interest').val();
        var breakdown = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < months; i++){
            var row = {};
            var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            row.month = monthNames[i%12]+', '+$('#year').val();
            row.principal = (amount/months).toFixed();
            row.interest = ((amount*interest)/months).toFixed();
            row.balance = (amount*(1-i/months)).toFixed();
            breakdown.push(row);
        }
        $('#mortgageTable').DataTable({
            data: breakdown,
            destroy: true,
            dom: 'ftip',
            columnDefs: [
                {targets: 0, data: 'month', title: 'Month'},
                {targets: 1, data: 'principal', title: 'Principal'},
                {targets: 2, data: 'interest', title: 'Interest'},
                {targets: 3, data: 'balance', title: 'Balance'},
            ]
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mortgagecalc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Loan amount, USD:</label><input id="amount" restrict="integer"></input></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Loan term, months:</label><input id="term" restrict="integer"></input></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>First month:</label><select id="month">
    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="Jan">Feb</option>
    <option value="Jan">Mar</option>
    <option value="Jan">Apr</option>
    <option value="Jan">May</option>
    <option value="Jan">Jun</option>
    <option value="Jan">Jul</option>
    <option value="Jan">Aug</option>
    <option value="Jan">Sep</option>
    <option value="Jan">Oct</option>
    <option value="Jan">Nov</option>
    <option value="Jan">Dec</option>
</select>
<select id="year">
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Interest rate, %:</label><input id="interest" restrict="float"></input></div>
<button id="breakdown">Mortgage breakdown</button>
<table id="mortgageTable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And I got it working in a way, but the major issue I'm facing, the payments for each consecutive month should get decreased due to decreasing debt leftover and as such decreased interest payments.

Is there a way I can cope with that using datatables features?

So, my expected output for $100,000, 36 months, 5% should be like:

```
principal   interest    balance
2777.78 416.67  100000.00
2777.78 405.09  97222.22
2777.78 393.52  94444.44
2777.78 381.94  91666.67
2777.78 370.37  88888.89
```

In my current implementation, only the first row is calculated properly and the rest row do not have 'balance' and 'interest' decreased proportionally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, your calculations do not need any 'recursion'. To achieve desired output you can make use of [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option in order to calculate your interest payments, based on the current remainder and month.

So, basically, the solution boils down to the following line:

```
render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())*$('#interest').val()/1200).toFixed(2)}
```

However, there's a whole lot of other problems in your code:

- your date string will not be evaluated properly starting from second year, so you'd better do something, like:

```
const monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const datatable = $('#mortgageTable').DataTable({
        ...
        columns: [
            {data: 'month', title: 'Month', render: (data, type, row, meta) => monthNames[meta.row%12]+', '+parseFloat(parseFloat($('#year').val())+Math.floor(meta.row/12))},
            ...
        ]
    });
```

- you don't really need to destroy and create your DataTable upon inputs change, you may simply purge its contents and fill it with relevant data and that would be much faster in terms of performance
- taking into account you may achieve your goal with `render` options, you may save some more performance rendering your table on the fly (without preparing data object in advance)

Additionally, you may take into consideration few suggestions that might make your code a bit more efficient:

- you may populate month options HTML with a single line:

```
const monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$('#month').append(monthNames.reduce((options, month) => options += `<option value="${month}">${month}</option>`,''));
```

- your years `<select>` may be populated with options dynamically either, so that you don't need to update your HTML each year:

```
$('#year').append([...Array(2)].reduce((options, dummy, index) => options += `<option value="${(new Date()).getFullYear()+index}">${(new Date()).getFullYear()+index}</option>`,''))
```

- you may implement custom sorting for your first column data for better user experience, e.g. if you have `type: 'mmmyyyy'` assigned to your first column, custom sorting may be achieved by something, like:

```
    const monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    const dateVal = str => {
        const dateParts = str.split(', ');
        return parseFloat(12*dateParts[1])+monthNames.indexOf(dateParts[0]);
    };
    Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
        'mmmyyyy-asc': (a, b) => dateVal(a)-dateVal(b),
        'mmmyyyy-desc': (a, b) => dateVal(b)-dateVal(a),
    });
```

Eventually, the complete live demo of your code, might be something, like:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

    //restrict input to certain types
    $('[restrict]').on('keyup', function () {
        switch ($(this).attr('restrict')) {
        case 'integer':
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ''));
        case 'float':
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\.0-9]*/g, ''));
        }
    });
 
 //re-used month names array
 const monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 //turning 'MMM, YYYY' into value
 const dateVal = str => {
  const dateParts = str.split(', ');
  return parseFloat(12*dateParts[1])+monthNames.indexOf(dateParts[0]);
 };
 
 //populate 'year', 'month' options dynamically
 $('#month').append(monthNames.reduce((options, month) => options += `<option value="${month}">${month}</option>`,''));
 $('#year').append([...Array(2)].reduce((options, dummy, index) => options += `<option value="${(new Date()).getFullYear()+index}">${(new Date()).getFullYear()+index}</option>`,''))
 
 //breakdown frame
 const breakdown = () => [...Array(parseFloat($('#term').val()) || 0)].map(item => ['month', 'principal', 'interest', 'balance'].reduce((res, header) => ({...res, [header]:''}), {}));
 
 //feed datatable
 const datatable = $('#mortgageTable').DataTable({
  dom: 'ftip',
  data: breakdown(),
  columns: [
   {data: 'month', type: 'mmmyyyy', title: 'Month', render: (data, type, row, meta) => monthNames[meta.row%12]+', '+parseFloat(parseFloat($('#year').val())+Math.floor(meta.row/12))},
   {data: 'principal', title: 'Principal', render: () => ($('#amount').val()/$('#term').val()).toFixed(2)},
   {data: 'interest', title: 'Interest', render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())*$('#interest').val()/1200).toFixed(2)},
   {data: 'balance', title: 'Balance', render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())).toFixed(2)}
  ]
 });
 
 //datatable sorting by 'MMM, YYYY' value
 Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'mmmyyyy-asc': (a, b) => dateVal(a)-dateVal(b),
  'mmmyyyy-desc': (a, b) => dateVal(b)-dateVal(a),
 });
 
 //hide datatable initially
 $('.dataTables_wrapper').hide();
 
 //button click handler
 $('#breakdown').on('click', () => {
  datatable.clear().rows.add(breakdown()).draw();
  $('.dataTables_wrapper').show();
 });
 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mortgagecalc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Loan amount, USD:</label><input id="amount" restrict="integer"></input></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Loan term, months:</label><input id="term" restrict="integer"></input></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>First month:</label><select id="month"></select>
<select id="year"></select></div>
<div style="display:block; margin: 5px"><label>Interest rate, %:</label><input id="interest" restrict="float"></input></div>
<button id="breakdown">Mortgage breakdown</button>
<table id="mortgageTable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```